# SQL : query large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I want to query a large data set in SQL - which is the right approach?

```
declare @datetime Datetime

select * 
from sales 
where salesdate <= @datetme
```

or:

```
select * 
from sales 
where salesdate < (select GetDate())
```

or:

```
select * 
from sales 
where salesdate < GetDate()
```

or by using `NOW()`

Comment: Assuming that you are using SQL Server: I would be **very** surprised if there was any difference between those queries.

Comment: No Im asking about the performance

Comment: Yes. And we think that the performance will not differ.

Comment: `NOW()` is a `MySQL` variant of `GETDATE()`, so which one you use is dependent on the DBMS you're using.  Also note that your query would return literally every record (assuming you don't have records with a sales date greater than this very second).

Comment: If `salesdate` is properly indexed, there is no need to worry about which of these performs better (they're all essentially the same, and will very likely compile to the same query plan).  The main issue with your query will be the *sheer number of records* being returned.  That has nothing to do with your query, and isn't something you can optimize by writing the query any differently or indexing, etc.  That has everything to do with the fact that it will have to return a large amount of data over the pipe.

Comment: The first query as posted will return exactly zero rows ever because your variable is not set so it will be NULL. The second and third queries are exactly the same.

Answer (score 6):

All three will have same execution plan other than 0% ASSIGN stage for variable in query no. 1. But it will turn out to be a good practice in the long run to always initialize variable as DATETIME and then use for comparison. When you have long comparisons to make this way, user will get the habit of formatting datetime in a variable and comparing column against those variables. Otherwise, it becomes a habit of formatting SQL column and then comapring it with date. That formats datetime field in every data row for comparison with value and makes datetime comparisons slow.

For this particular query, for readability and ease of use, you can select query no. 3 [Select * from sales where salesdate < GetDate()].

Answer (score 1):

`Select * from sales where salesdate < GetDate()` would seem the most logical way of doing it, its less SQL than `Select * from sales where salesdate < ( Select GetDate())` and there's not much point in declaring a variable like the first option if your only running a one off query, if you're going to use this a lot or in a stored procedure then adding the variable in would make sense.

But look at the Execution Plans and see which performs the best